# Making an android app to add two numbers

Tags: java, android

The user enters two numbers in EditText and on the click of a button their sum is to be displayed in a TextView field.On running my code on the emulator I get "Launcher stopped working".
Here's my java code:

```
 package com.snandi.sum;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    TextView tv;
    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {



                   int int1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString().trim());//Edited line 
                   int int2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString().trim());//edited line 


                int sum = int1 + int2;

                   //display the sum on the textView
                   tv.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }


        });
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my xml code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.snandi.sum.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post your logcat log so we can see what the error is. :)

Comment: Launcher stopped working mean emulator not working, there is no issue in your code, try to run code in different emulator.

Comment: logcat shows following message07-04 15:42:58.108: D/AndroidRuntime(1372): Shutting down VM
07-04 15:42:58.108: W/dalvikvm(1372): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a4cba8)
07-04 15:42:58.118: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 15:42:58.118: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): Process: com.snandi.numbers, PID: 1372
07-04 15:42:58.118: E/AndroidRuntime(1372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.snandi.numbers/com.snandi.numbers.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Dhawal Sodha Parmar Emulator is working fine for other applications